# Replacing text in a file using java

Tags: java

I have a text file named FormatString.java. It contains a few words. OUt of those words, I want to replace the word oldstring with newstring and rename the final result as t.txt . I have written the code. Technically it should work. The problem is that I dod not know where to save the FormatString.java file. Do I save it in the same class folder where the program ReplacingText is saved or do I save it somewhere else.
I go to the command prompt and into the folder where the ReplacingText.class and the FormatString.java file is saved and type the below statement:

java ReplacingText FormatString.java t.txt oldstring newstring

```
package replacingtext;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ReplacingText 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

        if (args.length !=4)
        {
            System.out.println(
            "Usage: java ReplaceText sourceFile targetFile oldStr newStr");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        File sourceFile = new File(args[0]);
        if(!sourceFile.exists())
        {
            System.out.println("Source file " + args[0]+" does not exist");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        File targetFile = new File(args[1]);
        if (targetFile.exists())
        {
            System.out.println("Target File " + args[1] + "already exist");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        Scanner input = new Scanner(sourceFile);
        PrintWriter output2 = new PrintWriter(targetFile);

        while (input.hasNext())
        {
            String s1=input.nextLine();
            String s2=s1.replaceAll(args[2],args[3]);
            output2.println(s2);
        }
        input.close();
        output2.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running the program from command line, maybe you wan to put the `FormatString.java` in your `bin` folder.

With Eclipse

```
ProjectRootFolder
               bin
                  FromatString.java
                  ReplacingText.class

               src
                  ReplacingText.java
```

With Netbeans

```
ProjectRootFolder
               build
                   classes
                        FromatString.txt

                        replacinttext
                                ReplacingText.class

               src
                  ReplacingText.java
```

> **`C:\Users\Dhaval\Desktop\Java Assignment\ReplacingText\build\classes>java replacingtext.ReplaceText FormatString.java public private`**

Try to run the program like I have above with all the files in the same Directorys like I have